# Error in redirect joomla 1.5 to joomla 2.5

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I have this website: `home-bradgardnerconstruction-org` which was built on joomla 1.5 without the sef link so the links looks like this

```
www-bradgardnerconstruction.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=17:admin&catid=15:testimonials&Itemid=13
```

I've built a new website which is this 'bradgardnerconstruction-com' on joomla 2.5 
in which the links look like this

```
www.bradgardnerconstruction-com/brad-gardner-construction/brad-gardner-construction-company-profile.html
```

I am trying to redirect the old website using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^home\.bradgardnerconstruction\.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.home\.bradgardnerconstruction\.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.bradgardnerconstruction\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

but is giving me a bunch of 500 errors and 404 errors on google webmaster 
basically what is doing is changing the links from

```
home.bradgardnerconstruction-org/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&layout=blog&id=16&Itemid=16
```

to this

```
http://www.bradgardnerconstruction.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&layout=blog&id=16&Itemid=16
```

and is messing up everything.

Any advise?

Comment: Google Webmaster takes a bit of time to figure out the change. Google will need to re-index the new site, and figure out the new structure. One way to speed up this process would be to submit a new sitemap for the site, and remove any old ones.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you are going to be able to change the old URLs to the new, unless there is a strong logic between the old URLs and the new that you could calculate, eg if all the itemids and article ids are exactly the same as before.

If not, I think you'd have to write an individual redirect for every page of the old site, or just redirect all pages to the homepage.

If you have to do individual redirects, you could either write them in the htaccess file or keep that as it is and use the redirect component in the 2.5 version, which would be redirecting a redirect but can be simpler to set up (though not much tbh).

Comment: yes richard but the part is that when tryed to do the redirect page by page from the old website to the new website using 301 redirect /old website to new website it kept trowing me 500 errors which was worst.